# How to Stop or Cancel a task in azure?

Tags: azure

I tried to reset my vm ssh details & seems VMagent was not working properly, after the task started it looping to showing `Resetting Ssh key..`.Is there any way i can stop the running task ?

Comment: What task are you referring to? VM's don't have a "task" model. There are webjobs / functions. Other than that, not sure what you mean.

Comment: What i meant is that, when i initiated "Reset ssh key" from dashboard, the targeted vm was not running VMAgent, so the "Reset ssh key" function fails & it keeps retrying it, is there any way to stop it ?